# Passing a function reference through data attribute in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, recaptcha

I am trying to pass a function into recaptcha to be used as a callback. I need to write:

`data-callback="function"`

In Vue how do I add the function reference? 
I've tried:

`data-callback="{{ this.submitFocus }}"`

`data-callback="this.submitFocus"`

I'm using Vue 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recaptcha2 uses the `data-callback` string to call a globally available function.

From what I can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display), it doesn't look like there's a programmatic way to set this so you might have to use something like this

```js
beforeMount () {
  window.submitFocus = () => { // using arrow function to preserve "this"
    this.submitFocus()
  }
},
beforeDestroy () {
  delete window.submitFocus
}
```

with

```html
data-callback="submitFocus"
```

in your template. The attribute value just needs to match the function added to `window`.

Answer (score 0):

`data-callback` is an html attribute of a DOM element, it's just a string. It does not know about the context of your object instance, ie. `this`.

So, you can't use `this` when setting the attribute for your ReCaptcha, it will only understand functions that can be called without `this`.

If you had a function defined as

```
function submitFocus(){ ... }
```

globally, you could get ReCaptcha to call it by setting `data-callback` to `submitFocus` without the reference to `this`.

```
data-callback="submitFocus"
```